# Breeding age range for terrestrial geckos

Tags: reptiles, breeding, geckos

I have a female African Fat Tailed gecko who is (15+) years of age. I have a feeling this is too old for breeding. **At what age range is it acceptable to breed terrestrial geckos?** Males? Females?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.theurbanboa.com/breeding-african-fat-tailed-gecko) information states that African Fat Tailed Geckos are in a position to breed when sexually mature, which occurs between 15 to 18 months of age, although, can be younger. It is also worth noting that African Fat Tailed Geckos are recommended to be bred between spring and autumn to yield the best results.

While there is no 'limit' on the age to breed, I would personally give yours a miss due to possible infertility or an increased percentage of 'dud eggs' as the recommended life expectancy is between 10 - 25 years according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_fat-tailed_gecko).